# Klein system. CSS isn't working

Tags: php, css

I'm testing Klein routing system, https://github.com/chriso/klein.php
 it's awesome but i can't get my css ant images to run

This is my directory structure:

```
index.php
.htaccess
vendor
views
  includes
  assets
    css
    images
```

And here's one of my includes line of code where i try to access my assets/css:

```
<link href="../assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I tried everything. Every possible hint would be great, thanks.

EDIT:
now i think it can be problem in my htaccess. how to make that url won't rewrite if it's css or img?
my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What does “everything” include?

Comment: @AndersG `./` is superfluous/error-prone.

Comment: You're absolutely right, so I deleted the whole comment. I'd still stick to my first suggestion though, basing the paths on the root such as `/views/assets/css/main.css`. But I guess you've already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is most likely wrong (unless the code you pulled it from is in the include or assets folder). the ".." literally means "up one level". So if you code is in the .htaccess folder (which it usually is I believe) or any folder on that level the correct link would be:

```
href='../views/assets/css/main.css'
```

If your code is in css or images (not sure why it would be) the correct link would be:

```
href='../css/main.css'
```

Good lcuk!

Comment: that line of code is in includes/head.php i put ../ so i can access assets/css, but that seems to not work

Comment: It is unlikely that `../css/main.css` is the correct URI. Including a script in PHP does _not_ mean (as-is) that the current working directory is changed to the directory of the include. The correct URI is more along `views/assets/css/main.css` because `index.php` is in the directory above `views/`.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, if the file is located inside the include folder, then your link is correct and I would need more specific information to help you out.